# Does NASA yet have an official history of the Shuttle?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle, reference-request

NASA has official "histories" of many of their past programs.  These are more about  people and decisions, not technical details.

- [This New Ocean: A History of Project Mercury](https://www.history.nasa.gov/SP-4201/toc.htm)
- [On the Shoulders of Titans: A History of Project Gemini](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/SP-4203/toc.htm)
- [Stages to Saturn](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4206/contents.htm)
- [Chariots for Apollo](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/SP-4205/contents.html)

Is there a similar treatment of the Shuttle program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the very early part of the shuttle program, leading up to the awarding of contracts, there's [The Space Shuttle Decision (SP-4221)](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4221/contents.htm).

The same author wrote a Volume II, [Development of the Space Shuttle 1972-1981](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL8828768M/Development_of_the_Space_Shuttle_1972-1981_%28History_of_the_Space_Shuttle_Volume_2%29), sponsored by the NASA History Office but published by the Smithsonian Institution; unlike Volume I, it does not appear to be available on the NASA website.

Searching [NASA History's full book list](https://history.nasa.gov/books_sort_SP.html) for `shuttle` yields only a handful of titles:

- [Shuttle-Mir: The United States and Russia Share History's Highest Stage](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4225.pdf)
- The Space Shuttle Decision
- [The Spoken Word III: Recollections of Dryden's History; The Shuttle Years](https://history.nasa.gov/monograph52.pdf)
- [Toward A History Of The Space Shuttle: An Annotated Bibliography Part I](https://history.nasa.gov/708235main_Shuttle_Bibliography_1-ebook.pdf)
- [Toward A History Of The Space Shuttle: An Annotated Bibliography Part II](https://history.nasa.gov/708066main_Shuttle_Bibliography_2-ebook.pdf)

Comment: There's *Wings in Orbit* but I don't recommend it, it was a huge disappointment. https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/wingsinorbit

Comment: Oh, and Volume 2 of *Decision* covers development. Both volumes are excellent.